# What's the purpose of this SignInManager call when the controller has the [Authorize] attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Having set up a default ASP.Net MVC 5 application, I fail to understand why the below snippet has a call to SignInManager.

This is in the ManageController, which has the [Authorize] attribute.

```
    //
    // POST: /Manage/RemoveLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> RemoveLogin(string loginProvider, string providerKey)
    {
        ManageMessageId? message;
        var result = await UserManager.Get().RemoveLoginAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>(), new UserLoginInfo(loginProvider, providerKey));
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.Get().FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInManager.Get().SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false, rememberBrowser: false);
            }
            message = ManageMessageId.RemoveLoginSuccess;
        }
        else
        {
            message = ManageMessageId.Error;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("ManageLogins", new { Message = message });
    }
```

I am wondering if, whenver I retrieve the authenticated user, I should repeat this step, i.e. check if the user is null and if not, await SignInAsync.
Edit: check if the user is null and if *it is*, await SignInAsync

Now, I've created a new controller, that I've given the [Authorize] attribute, and in the Index() function of the controller, I do:

```
        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
```

If I load that page in two tabs, sign out in one of them and then refresh the page, I'm redirected to the login screen. I've attached a debugger and have been unable to cause a case where the SignInManager is hit.

In what scenario would the user be not-null?

Comment: I haven't understood [IUserLoginStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IUserLoginStore.cs) completely to be fair. The snippet removes a login for the user of the request which can be the login currently used by that user. The call to the `SignInManager` ensures that the affected user stays authenticated (signed-in). If you remove the last login you would be effectively logged-off. In that case you will be signed-in (authenticated) but - probably - no longer authorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They do entirely different things. The `Authorize` attribute checks that the user is authenticated and authorized to access the action (based on role permissions and such). It doesn't authenticate the user. That's what the call to `SignInManager` is for. It actually authenticates the user, so that the user can then pass checks made by the `Authorize` attribute.

As for when the user might be null, effectively, if the action is protected by `Authorize` it probably never will be. It would have to take some strange confluence of events where the user was found in the database in order to sign them in, but then somehow was removed by the time you tried to retrieve it. In other words: not bloody likely. Still, it's good practice to always perform a null-check like this when a value could potentially be null, which `user` could.

Comment: Interestingly, now that I've posed this question, I find it remarkable that the if-statement checks for user != null ..... Is that a typo or am I still missing something?

Comment: @Diana no typos there. What is so confusing about null-check?

Comment: @Diana Well the `UserManager` uses an [IUserStore](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IUserStore.cs) which contains users. The `ClaimsPrincipal` contains "n" [Identities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.identities(v=vs.110).aspx) which can return a *UserId* which has no reference to any user of the store.
Thus `null` can be returned by `FindByIdAsync`. Both sides can be configured separately and the snippet tries to handle some scenarios.

Comment: Ah, thanks to the additional comments, I think I sort of get it now. I see that this snippet is associated with the ManageController, which manages authentication methods and change password. After any such change, the user is re-authenticated. Am I correct in thinking that, once we're in a method in a controller with [Authorize] attribute that does not make any such changes to the user settings, I don't have to make any calls to SignInAsync?

Comment: @Diana Correct, if you don't want (or need) to change the authentication or authorization of the session itself (i.e. update roles or claims for current user) you don't need to use the `SignInManager`. You use the `AuthorizeAttribute` to (kind of) flag a method as *"user has to be authorized to do that"* and the application verifies the user of the request before entering the method - no matter what action is to be done.